# Form Request data not passing to Controller through Get method in Laravel+Jquery E-commerce project

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-8, e-commerce

**Here is my blade file code**

```
<div class="search-area">
    <form action="{{ route('search.product') }}" method="GET">
        <div class="control-group">
            <input class="search-field" name="search" />
            <button class="search-button" type="submit"></button>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

**My web.php code is:**

```
Route::get('/search-products',[SearchController::class,'searchProduct'])->name('search.product');
```

**My Controller code is:**

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request){
    return $search = $request->search;
}
```

---

> **I can access Request data from Controller when I use POST method.**

---

**Please help me to find the soluation.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: $request->input(“search”)

Comment: @Maksim Already tried, but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should send back your search aria data like:

```
oute::get('/search-products/{name}',[SearchController::class,'searchProduct'])->name('search.product');
```

Comment: So, what will be the blade file code?

Comment: I give you another answer check it out @TanvirBhuiyan

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to send data for your blade:

```
$data = YOUR_MODEL::findOrFail($id);
return view('YOUR_VIEW_BLADE', compact('data'));
```

then you can use

```
@foreach($data as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->last_name}}</td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Dont forget this is an example you need to modify with your app.